# why program can't see global variable?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

here in my code,program can't variable n and i am surpirsed why it happens?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int d=3;
int n=12;

template<class T>
class pqi
{
    vector<int>pq;
    vector<int>qp;
    vector<T>&a(n);
    void exch(int i,int j)
    {
        int t=pq[i];
        pq[i]=pq[j];
        pq[j]=t;
        qp[pq[i]]=i;
        qp[pq[j]]=j;
    }
    void fixup(int k)
    {
        while(k>1 && a[pq[(k+d-2)/d]]>qp[pq[k]])
        {
            exch(k,(k+d-2)/d);k=(k+d-2)/d;
        }
    }
    void fixdown(int k,int n)
    {
        int j;
        while((j=d*(k-1)+2)<=n)
        {
            for(int i=j+1;i<j+d&& i<=n;i++)
                if(a[pq[j]]>a[pq[i]]) j=i;
            if(!(a[pq[k]]>a[pq[j]])) break;
            exch(k,j);k=j;
        }
    }
public:
    pqi(int n,const vector<T>&a,int d=3):a(a),pq(n+1,0),qp(n+1,0),n(0),d(d){}
    int empty() const
    {
        return n==0;
    }
    void insert(int v)
    {
        pq[++n]=v ;
        qp[v]=n;
        fixup(n);
    }
    int getmin()
    {
        exch(1,n);
        fixdown(1,n-1);
        return pq[--n];
    }
    void lower(int k)
    {
        fixup(qp[k]);
    }
};
int main()
{
    vector<int>s(n);
    pqi<int>a(n,s,d);
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
        a.insert(rand()%(RAND_MAX+i));
    while(!a.empty())
    {
        cout<<a.getmin()<<"  ";;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i have declared outside of  code as global variable,butit can'see it and says

```
1>c:\users\\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\multiway_heap\multiway_heap\multiway_heap.cpp(12): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'n'
1>          c:\users\\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\multiway_heap\multiway_heap\multiway_heap.cpp(62) : see reference to class template instantiation 'pqi<T>' being compiled
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

really i can't understand such behavior,please help me to clarify what i am doing wrong

Comment: what is line `vector<T>&a(n);` supposed to do?

Comment: http://www.scribd.com/doc/83085976/53/Program-20-10-Multiway-heap-PQ-implementation

Comment: Besides the obvious problem pointed out in the answers, you are trying to initialize two non-existent member variables in yout ``pqi`` constructor, namely ``n`` and ``d``.

Answer (score 2):

```
 vector<T>&a(n);
```

What is this supposed to *be*? You're trying to... what? That's not a variable declaration nor a function declaration- and even if it were either of those, `n` would have no place there.

Comment: it is constructor for vector,i mean during inserting operations

Comment: @AleksiBeriashvili you cannot declare it *and* initialize it like that inside a class. In any case. ``vector<T>&`` is a **reference** to a vector.

Comment: I checked your link and clearly the code in there differs from yours. They declare a to be const vector<T>&a; NOT vector<T>&a(n) and they initialize it in the constructor's initialization list like so: a(a).

Comment: so how can i do it in alternative way?

Comment: Why can't you just do it their way? Just replace vector<T>&a(n); by const vector<T>&a;

Comment: in this case it gives me out of vector index range error

Comment: vector subscript out of range error

Comment: I noticed you changed the -- and ++ operators, in the book they are used as N++ and N--, you wrote them as --N and ++N. You might want to check if that fixes things.

Comment: i have changed,but it did not fixed problem,thanks for pointing  this

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<T>&a(n);
```

Not sure what you were trying to do with this, but it looks like you were trying to initialize the vector with size n which you can not do outside of the constructor (because it is not static).

Comment: please check link which i have posted

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that

```
vector<T>&a(n);
```

is not the right way to initialize the member variable. You should be using a constructor for this. However, I can see two plausible versions:

1. You actually meant `vector<T> a;`, i.e. not a *reference* to a vector. In this case, you can initialize the variable with an integer, like

   pqi::pqi() : a( n ) { }
2. You *do* want a reference to a vector - in that case, you need to initialize it with another vector (references cannot be rebound, only initialized) which you could pass to your constructor, like

   pqi::pqi( std::vector &v ) : a( v ) { }